# heroku git:remote -a command is not working

Tags: python, django, heroku-cli

heroku git:remote -a mymailapp-live

»   **Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 7.59.0.
Error: Command failed: git remote
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git**

it is showing me above error.
please help me.
i am hosting this using heroku-cli.

Comment: You are in the wrong folder. More exactly you are in a folder that is not a git repository.

Answer (score 0):

Type **

~$ git init

** and then run your command it should work and make sure you have git installed on your device

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).